Uncertainty about a proof that an algebraic closure is unique up to a non canonical isomorphism
I have a question about a certain passage, in the following proof of the statement:

Let $k$ be a field, its algebraic closure is unique up to a non canonical isomorphism.

Proof

Let $K$ and $L$ be respectively algebraic closures of $k$. There exists a field-homomorphism:
$$\varphi: K \longrightarrow L \ \text{such that} \ \varphi_{|k}=\operatorname{id}_{k}$$
It suffices to show that:
$$\varphi(K)=L$$
Which delivers:
$$L\cong K$$
So take $a\in L$, since $a$ is algebraic over $k$, $a$ is algebraic over $\varphi(K) \subset L$ aswell. So consider the minimal polynomial of $a$
, namely $P \in \varphi(K)[X]. $

Now the part that concerns me:

Since $\varphi(K)$ is algebraically closed, […]

The further conclusion is clear to me, as it doesn‘t elaborate latter statement I left it out. Beyond that this is an excerpt of a lecture-script, therefore it isn‘t published literature I could reference.
So my question is:
Why is  $\varphi(K)$ algebraically closed?
$\varphi(K)$ surely is a field, but I haven‘t been able to reason that $\varphi(K)$ is algebraically closed.

Since $\varphi$ is a field morphism it induces a morphism of algebras of polynomials, and since it preserves alL the coefficients of k you have won: for the root just take the image of the root in K

Remember, a field homomorphism is always injective, so $\varphi(K)$ is isomorphic to $K$. Of course you need to verify that being algebraically closed is preserved under isomorphism, but that's easy.

@Mark thats exactly what I have been missing, I was so focused on the $L \cong K$ iso. that I oversaw the obvious one, thanks!

Since $L$ is algebraic over $k$, so is $\varphi (K)$, so it only remains to show that every non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $\varphi(K)$ has a root in $\varphi (K)$.
Let us take such a polynomial $p$. Then $p= \varphi(q)$ with $q$ a polynomial with coefficients in $K$. It has a root $\lambda\in K$ thus:
$$p(\varphi(\lambda))= \varphi(q(\lambda)) = 0.$$
Here you go.

I wrote $\varphi(q)$ as an abuse of language
